# In the problem of loop detection in linked list I wrote this code and getting segementation error

Tags: c++, linked-list

at this test case i am getting segmentation error
Detect Loop in linked list problem at gfg
//
184 // this is value where loop is present
73 39 71 24 28 71 31 14 35 60 3 48 45 43 76 33 5 75 44 59 47 41 39 40 23 63 4 2 9 44 5 33 3 75 56 62 18 6 28 52 17 30 19 62 24 14 14 28 40 9 7 38 1 45 29 55 59 32 57 19 76 13 52 30 40 27 11 57 65 70 60 1 19 30 14 42 75 59 70 67 68 28 24 68 72 53 43 2 36 51 20 31 15 71 12 54 18 55 62 2 44 41 34 63 22 48 56 17 26 45 3 13 72 58 33 15 62 27 16 18 29 36 80 43 58 44 17 75 18 30 28 13 23 62 27 44 61 3 12 6 47 46 51 71 24 35 37 37 61 53 6 9 40 6 51 17 1 19 44 18 49 23 62 71 36 9 66 16 11 78 54 9 43 24 31 18 58 68 7 70 72 12 30 31
0 // these are the value of linked list
'''

```
class Solution
{
    public:
    //Function to check if the linked list has a loop.
    bool detectLoop(Node* head)
    {
       if(head->next  ==NULL  || head==NULL)
       {
           return false;
       }
       Node *slow=head;
       Node *fast=head;
       while(fast->next !=NULL && fast!=NULL)
       {
           slow=slow->next;
           fast=fast->next->next;
           if(slow==fast)
           {return true;
           }
       }
       return false;
    }
};
```

I wrote this code on gfg

Comment: `if(head->next  ==NULL  || head==NULL)` These should be reversed.

Comment: ^^ Same with `while(fast->next !=NULL && fast!=NULL)`

Comment: [Style]: replace `NULL` by `nullptr`.

Comment: With a bit more detailed wording: Instead of old (obsolete?) C *macros* (`NULL`) you should rather use new C++ *keywords* (`nullptr`) – though for actually checking for being a null pointer `if(!pointer)` is the more idiomatic test anyway...

Comment: *I wrote this code on gfg* - Bear in mind that this is a garbage website that promotes programming practices of extremely low quality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need at least exchange sub-expressions of logical expressions in the if statement and in the while loop. That is instead of

```
if(head->next  ==NULL  || head==NULL)
```

and

```
while(fast->next !=NULL && fast!=NULL)
```

you need to write

```
if( head == NULL || head->next  == NULL )
```

and

```
while( fast != NULL && fast->next != NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

In code line

```
fast=fast->next->next;
```

you are doing the second "next" without checking if the first "next" gave NULL.
This definitely will result in seg fault for all legal inputs when "fast" is one step before the terminating NULL.